# Matching Item Amounts From Two Lists

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to match the text values of two inventory spreadsheets, 'Product List' and 'Items Sold', and their corresponding numerical values. The problem is that in the system I use, if an item did not sell in that week, it doesn't appear on the spreadsheet, leaving gaps that would make an alphabetical descending order not work.

Is there a way to search 'Product List' Column A for the text value of each cell in 'Items Sold' Column A and append the corresponding numeric value in 'Items Sold' Column B to 'Product List'?

For example, 'Product List' and 'Items Sold' side by side would look like this:

```
Item      Current     Item       Amount
Item A          8     Item A          3
Item B         34     Item C          4
Item C          0     Item D         27
```

Since 'Item B' doesn't exist in the list, the desired result would be as follows:

```
Item      Current     Item       Amount
Item A          8     Item A          3
Item B         34          
Item C          0     Item C          4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use `vlookup` formula:

- Item: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Items Sold'!A:B,1,0),"")`
- Amount: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Items Sold'!A:B,2,0),"")`

This two formulas are to be dragged down for each row with the data.

**Single formula**

There's also construction `ArrayFormula` + `vlookup`. Here's single formula solution:

```
={"Item","Amount";ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(OFFSET(A1,1,,COUNTA(A2:A)),'Items Sold'!A:B,{1,2},0),""))}
```

I assumed that the date is placed like this:

```
    Product List          Items Sold
    A         B           A          B
1   Item      Current     Item       Amount
2   Item A          8     Item A          3
3   Item B         34     Item C          4
4   Item C          0     Item D         27
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the drag down method. Not sure what I was doing wrong but when I had previously applied the vlookup command it resulted in an error.